# Subclass Parse database class

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

In setting up the server aspect of my app that uses Parse, I realized that it would be very helpful if I could make subclasses on the actual database. Parse has a lot of information on subclassing, but this is on reference to creating a code subclass in the app to allow for code completion and debugging in the IDE. However I am looking for something else. I think it would be best explained through an example.

I have a `_User` class and I would like to create a `Player`, `Team` and `Coach` class that all inherit the columns of the `_User` superclass. This would save me form creating and maintaining all of these identical columns. This is exactly what subclassing means in normal programming, and I was wondering if it would be possible to do so on Parse, and if so, how would I do it? Thanks.

---

**Update:**

I recently found [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/class-inheritance) question on the archived section of Parse questions which describes what I am looking to do, and furthermore gives it a technical name: "single table inheritance." However the question and response do not go into detail on how to actually implement this. Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing the [link](https://www.parse.com/questions/class-inheritance) attached to the question, I found out that

> Relational databases don't support inheritance

so when trying to accomplish this, it cannot be done though the database (i.e. it cannot be achieved through Parse) so it needs to be mimicked on the client side.